# Node limit for published nodes per user

Tags: nodes

I am interested in limiting the nodes a user can publish.So Node limit module cannot help on this.
Someone suggested using userpoints and rules to achieve this.
How is this possible with these 2 modules?
Any help would be appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to [User Points Contributed module](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints_contrib): This module includes the module called **userpoints_nodelimit** which enables a limit on node creation based on user points.

---

However if you want to do it with the `userpoints` and `rules` module than the idea would be to [create the rule to grant certain point on publishing the new nodes](https://drupal.org/node/874372), and than create another rule whose `event` would be the node creation and in the `condition`  [check if the user already has reached limit](https://drupal.org/node/874390) than prevent node creation and display the custom message.

---

Alternatively one easy way to achieve the same is using the [hook_node_validate()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7), one example of using the same is as below:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_validate().
 */
function MyModule_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) {
  // For now assign the static value to MAX_NODES (No. of nodes),
  // however you can make it dynamic, and get those values using variable_get().
  $max_nodes = 'MAX_NODES';
  $node_count = 0;

  // Get the user uid from the global user variable.
  global $user;
  $user_id = $user->uid;

  if ((isset($node->uid))) {
    // Use entity query to get the number of nodes already published by this user.
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery;
    $node_count = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
      ->propertyCondition('uid', $user_id)
      ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
      ->count()
      ->execute();

    // Check if the node count exceeds the max_node value.
    if ($node_count > $max_nodes) {
      form_set_error('FIELD_NAME', t('Reached the maximum limit of creation of nodes.'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot make this work,is this possible you export the rules and pastes them here?

Comment: @sokratis I will try that, but meanwhile can you try the alternate method I have added in my answer just now.